# how to remove items in julia dict based on values?

Tags: julia

In  a dictionary of tuples, I'd like to remove all items whose values are Inf? I've tired the following but I got key error. How to do so?

```
my_dict = Dict(
    (18, 17, "t") => Inf,
    (18, 17, "t") => 20,
    (18, 17, "s") => Inf,
    (6, 5, "r") => Inf,
    (6, 5, "k8") => 19,
    (6, 5, "k9") => Inf,
    (10, 11, "e") => 200.0
)

my_dict = Dict([pair for pair in my_dict if !isinf(my_dict[pair])])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to remove all items whose values are Inf is to create a new `Dict` with only the key-value pairs that do not have `Inf` as the `value`. You can use a dictionary comprehension to achieve this as follows. Notice that creating an array for key-value pairs first is unnecessary, it allocates more memory.

```
julia> Dict(k => v for (k, v) in my_dict if v != Inf)
Dict{Tuple{Int64, Int64, String}, Real} with 3 entries:
  (6, 5, "k8")  => 19
  (18, 17, "t") => 20
  (10, 11, "e") => 200.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
filter!(((k,v),)->isfinite(v),my_dict);
```

or more succintly (using \circ composition):

```
filter!(isfinite∘last,my_dict);
```

which leave `my_dict` as:

```
julia> my_dict
Dict{Tuple{Int64, Int64, String}, Real} with 3 entries:
  (6, 5, "k8")  => 19
  (18, 17, "t") => 20
  (10, 11, "e") => 200.0
```

Comment: Thanks @Dan Getz it's very clean!